# hh:mm:ss.sss not recognised by Date.parse()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the time string `callLength` to milliseconds using the following function, but the return value is `NaN`.

Where am I going wrong?

```js
export const timeFunc = callLength => {
  console.log(callLength); // prints "00:00:32.000"
  const startingTime = Date.parse('1970-01-01T00:' + callLength + 'Z') // should print length in milliseconds?
  console.log(startingTime); // prints NaN
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding hours twice.

```
Date.parse('1970-01-01T00:' + "00:00:32.000" + 'Z')
```